# Performance degradation after upgrade

Tags: 11.04

today I have upgraded my netbook with Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. Here are my specs:

Asus EEE 1000HD
Celeron 900MHz (single core)
1 GB RAM
Integrated GPU (Intel) with 64MB shared memory
Sata disk

Always using Gnome (so in 10.10 Ubuntu Clasic)

It is not so amazing, but with 10.10 it was quite quick in comparassion with 11.04. Firstly, my login (after password inserted in GDM) increased from 15s to almost one minute. All of effects run very slow, slow is also rendering all windows (also web content in my Chrome).

Second (and I think, this is bug), when I log out, I can't login once more. No selection with lang, keyboard and enviroment appears. Is this normal? If yes, for me it means downgrade back to 10.10.

Thanks a lot!

Tomas Marcik (Czech Republic)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 11.04 is currently in Beta so things might not work right. Please [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an ASUS EEE 1000HE with 2Gb memory and have upgraded yesterday to 11.04. For the first 15 minutes or so I experienced the same slow-down, but then I restarted and the problem was gone.

My backup plan was to stick with 10.10 or jump to Xubuntu as I know that our EEE's don't have fancy graphics capabilities, but neither seem necessary now. 11.04 runs very well.

Kind Regards,
Bjorn